# When does navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

In a WKWebView, every time I tap on a URL, the `navigationType` is `.other`. When does `navigationType` equal `.linkActivated`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very unlikely. Maybe you are interpreting the raw values wrong?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationAction.navigationType.rawValue)
    // -1 "other" seen when assigning the url programatically
    // 0 "linkActivated" a link with an href attribute was tapped
    // 3 "reload" page was refreshed
}
```

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationtype) where you can click on the enumerations listed and and see their raw values

Comment: Thank you! somehow your description is clearer than the one inside the class documentation